# Trouble on writing the function for an account record pagination problem

Tags: calculus, functions, problem-solving

I have this problem about account record pagination. I have to write the function that describes the total pages needed to contain those account records.

This is the problem:

```
# Account record quantity to store per page
per_page € R 
# Account records to insert in pages
tot_acc € R 

# The total pages needed to store the `tot_account` quantity
f(per_page,tot_acc) = tot_page € R = ?
```

I need to find `f(per_page,tot_acc)`.

Comment: You'll need to explain what these quantities mean.

Comment: @joriki  I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking something like:

With all variables as integers, given the first page number of a set of accounts $i$, the number of accounts that can fit on a page $d$, the total number of accounts $n$, what is the number of the last page?

If so, then you need to use $\left\lceil \frac{n}{d}\right\rceil$ pages for the accounts where the brackets mean *ceiling* i.e. round up to the next integer. You need to add that to the page before the starting point $i-1$ to give the final page of the accounts
$$f(i,d,n) = \left\lceil \frac{n}{d}\right\rceil + i -1$$
or if you prefer
$$\text{tot_page} = f(\text{page, per_page, tot_acc})  = \left\lceil \frac{\text{tot_acc}}{\text{per_page}}\right\rceil + \text{page} -1.$$

Perhaps you were asking something else.